# Blank page on website randomly

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.6, .net

We are facing a strange issue intermittently where our web pages do not load and show "almost" a blank page. Some basic html is loaded but none which has our content and images in it.

For example: HTML for 1 component should be
[image]

But it is (basically its missing the content from the component and corresponding HTML)

[image]

The above screenshots from file DXAOutputcache.cs after line

string html = cachingWriter.ToString(); (Line: 95)

The issue gets resolved if we delete the cache manually.

We have confirmed the content service response is consistent every time, whether we have the issue on the webpage or not. We have also verified that all server parameters are doing good and there is no lack of memory or high CPU.

SDL.Web.Delivery version is 11.6.1123

**Update** : We have added further logs and it looks like an issue in method "CreateViewModel" in "DefaultModelBuilder.cs" but we are unable to pin point to any exact line of code which is causing the problem.

**Any help would be appreciated**